# Oracle: SQLPlus Query Concatenate Data With Headers

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to not only query different tables in my database and export them into a CSV, but also export data from multiple tables and concatenate them as columns into this CSV.

I start with the premise of being able to spool the contents of a table into a CSV file:

```
set colsep ','
set echo off
set feedback off
set linesize 1000
set sqlprompt ''
set headsep off
spool file.csv
select * from messages;
```

Now I want to grab certain components of multiple tables with no avail (with union and minus):

```
select col1, col2, col3 from messages
union
select col1, col2 from messagedata
union
select col1 from extradata;
```

In trying the above method, I'll get `ORA -1789 query block has incorrect number of result columns` meaning that I'm trying to match up the wrong number of columns (which I'm trying to avoid by just appending columns in my output).

And given either *union* or *minus* it will error on the wrong datatype, but that being because it's just trying to append it to the columns from my first query.

My goal there is to create a query that produces similar output:

```
| col1(messages)  | ... |  col2(messagedata) | ... |  col3(extradata) |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  message         ,...    ,messagedata        ,...   ,extradata      
  message         ,...    ,messagedata        ,...   ,extradata
  message         ,...    ,messagedata        ,...   ,extradata
```

So two questions:

- Is it possible for me to concatenate the data from multiple tables into a column output like above? As in create *new* columns to output instead of appending to existing columns?
- How might I give a header to my data (custom or already defined by
  the identifier in the table) at the top of the column?

Comment: You want to `JOIN` these table rather than `UNION`. Now how are the tables related to each other?

Comment: You can't output into columns independently. A column is a part of a row. Even if you don't have any relations between tables then you need to `JOIN` them using row number for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you either join your tables if they're related to each other. One way to do it if `col1` is the common column

```
SELECT COALESCE(m.col1, d.col1, e.col1) column_name1,
       m.col2 column_name2,
       m.col3 column_name3,
       d.col2 column_name4,
       e.col2 column_name5
  FROM messages m FULL JOIN messagedata d
    ON m.col1 = d.col1 FULL JOIN extradata e
    ON d.col1 = e.col1
```

Sample output:

```
| COLUMN_NAME1 | COLUMN_NAME2 | COLUMN_NAME3 | COLUMN_NAME4 | COLUMN_NAME5 |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|            1 |      value12 |      value13 |        data1 |   extradata1 |
|            2 |      value21 |      value31 |        data2 |   extradata2 |
```

or you `UNION` them in this way

```
SELECT col1 column_name1, col2 column_name2, col3 column_name3
  FROM messages
 UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, NULL
  FROM messagedata
 UNION ALL
SELECT col1, NULL, NULL
  FROM extradata
```

**Note** that the number of columns and their respective data types should be the same for all `SELECT`s that you `UNION`. To overcome this you can inject constant values (e.g. `NULL`) and  convert/cast column values to some common type (e.g. `VARCHAR2`) if needed.

Sample output:

```
| COLUMN_NAME1 | COLUMN_NAME2 | COLUMN_NAME3 |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|            1 |      value12 |      value13 |
|            2 |      value21 |      value31 |
|            1 |        data1 |       (null) |
|            2 |        data2 |       (null) |
|            1 |       (null) |       (null) |
|            2 |       (null) |       (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83cea/3)** demo

Comment: My tables are all related (at least the ones I'm querying). However in order to do that, I need to have a common column?

Comment: Luckily the majority of my tables have a single column with the same data. I'll give it a shot. Also SQLFiddle is quite useful!

Comment: OK. Sounds great! Good luck. If you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.