# Sort three tables using a common column in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm doing an android project.. and m not that familier with the platform..

I have to sort 3 tables in my database using a common column..the table details are given below...

Table Location
     (String date,
      String day,
      String time,
      String location_address,
      String latitude,
      String longitude,
      long timeInMilli)

Table call
     (String name,
     String number,
     String type,
     String date,
     String time,
     String duration,
     long timeInMilli)

Table SMS
     (String date,
     String time,
     String type, 
     String add, 
     String contact,
     String sub,
     String msg, 
     long timeInMilli)

I have to sort these table based on timeInMilli column...

Anyone plz help me,,, i need that code immeeediately as my project submsn date is on 23rd october... plz help me... thanks in advance...

Comment: How exactly should the result of this operation look?

Comment: i need a table lyk this as the result, table SORTED(id, String call_or_sms_or_location, corresponding rowID, Date, TimeinMilli) ---- call_or_sms_or_location says wether it's in call table, location table or sms table.. corresponding rowID, is the id of call or sms or location row...

Comment: plz..anyone give me a solution

Comment: Please be patient. You will not receive a solution immediately in the case of most questions. Considering you have received downvotes means that users deem your question to be poorly researched and demonstrated, considering it is also schoolwork. You should show an example of how you're creating the tables within your question.

Answer (score 2):

To just concatenate the results of multiple queries, use [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound); the column names of the result are taken from the first subquery:

```
SELECT rowid AS ID, 'call' AS c_or_s_or_l, date, timeInMilli FROM call
UNION ALL
SELECT rowid,       'SMS',                 date, timeInMilli FROM SMS
UNION ALL
SELECT rowid,       'location',            date, timeInMilli FROM Location
ORDER BY timeInMilli
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily know syntax differences in SQLite but I can show you an example in Oracle, but the concept will remain the same.

So I set up a subset of your data. Tables MLOCATION, MCALL, and SMS. MLOCATION contains the date, day, and timeinmilli. MCALL contains the name, number, date, and timeinmilli. SMS contains the date, type, message and timeinmilli. So as you notice I must have 'timeinmlili' in common across all columns.

What I do is coalesce the columns according to the value of timeinmilli. You can specify any and all values that you want with their column header, and then you select the tables with timeinmilli and say "full join" where that value is equal to the value in the other table.

```
select coalesce(l.MILLI, c.MILLI, s.MILLI) TIMEINMILLI,
  l.DDAY D_DAY,
  c.DNAME D_NAME,
  c.NUM D_NUMBER,
  s.DTYPE D_TYPE,
  s.MSG MESSAGE
from MLOCATION l full join MCALL c
  on l.MILLI = c.MILLI full join SMS s
  on c.MILLI = s.MILLI;
```

Which given the tables I created gives me the output:

```
TIMEINMILLI    D_DAY      D_NAME    D_NUMBER    D_TYPE  MESSAGE
1381730400000  Monday     Thatguy   4786217452  Type1   This is a message
1381903200000  Wednesday  Someone   4897414821  Type3   Word
1381989600000  Thursday   Nafi      1234567891  Type2   LOL
```

You may also see the full example I provided in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43e8e/1). Remember I did this in Oracle, however you may change the database type to SQLite to test your own tables and schema.

Also give a thumbs up to the guy who originally pointed me in this direction - [peterm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148860/1861357).

Comment: You are assuming that the records in the three tables are related with each other. Records without common timestamps will not be shown.

Comment: Yes that is true. I wanted to show a simple instance of conjoining the data by timestamps, after which he would be a step closer into sorting the conjoined data.